# Worksheet methods Activate and Copy do nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a workbook print macro initiated from a custom ribbon button. I have to iterate over a subset of the work sheets, copy them, do some formatting, and hide the originals before printing. However worksheets methods activate and copy do nothing and I don't get an error.

The ribbon button executes this macro code in Modules.Module1

```
Sub bmPrintWB(control As IRibbonControl)
    g_printWorkbook = True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut
    g_printWorkbook = False
End Sub
```

g_printWorkbook is a global boolean in Modules.Module2

This triggers ThisWorkbook.BeforePrint

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

If g_printWorkbook Then
    bmPrintWorkbookWithSBS
    Exit Sub
End If
```

bmPrintWorkbookWithSBS is in Modules.Module1

```
Sub bmPrintWorkbookWithSBS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tmpWs As Worksheet
    Dim sbsWorksheets As Collection
    Dim sbsTempWorksheets As Collection
    Dim tmpNumber As Integer
    Dim bAllowSBSPrint As Boolean
    Dim iResult As Integer
    Dim bCalc As Boolean

    Set sbsWorksheets = New Collection
    Set sbsTempWorksheets = New Collection


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then
        bCalc = True
    Else
        bCalc = False
    End If

    If bCalc Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And IsSheetSideBySide(ws.Name) Then
            sbsWorksheets.Add ws
        End If
    Next ws

    tmpNumber = 1
    For Each ws In sbsWorksheets
    ws.Activate

    If Not ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Name Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set up the global names
    iResult = SetGlobalWorksheetNames()
    iResult = SetGlobalCallerBasedOnSheetName(ws.Name)
    Set tmpWs = CreateSBSTemp(ws, tmpNumber)
    If Not tmpWs Is Nothing Then
        sbsTempWorksheets.Add tmpWs
        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        tmpNumber = tmpNumber + 1
    End If

    Next ws

    g_ribbonPrinting = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut
    g_ribbonPrinting = False

    For Each ws In sbsWorksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    For Each ws In sbsTempWorksheets
       ws.Delete
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If bCalc Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Basically no worksheet method calls (Activate, Copy) in the bottom sub or the called function do anything. I've tried turning on ScreenUpdating just for ws.Activate, and that didn't help either.

As for why I don't just run the subroutine directly from the ribbon button. It's because the vba project is password protected and I couldn't figure out to give the ribbon persmissions. Setting a global variable that's seen in beforePrint was my workaround.

Comment: Does the Sub for bmPrintWorkbookWithSB see the sbsworksheets? Are these global variables? It may be that nothing is selected. You can make sure that your sub is being called by addding a `Debug.Print("I made it to the last sub")` or something more helpful. If it is being called, I think it will be a variable problem.

Comment: The sbsWorksheets collection is populated with the sheets I want. I can debug and see that I make it into the For loop. I've debugged all the way up to that step, so all the blocks are getting called, and the variables are as expected.

Comment: How many Excel files are involved - just 1 with the VBA code and the to be printed sheets? Or more workbooks or an Addin - then `ThisWorkbook` is different from `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Just one file. There's only one workbook.